# Load operation failed for query 'getEmployees'

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, wcf-ria-services

I'm using SL4 and RIA Services to build a new solution based on the Silverlight Business Application template.

I have a problem with get huge data from server, in this table "Employee" i have about 20000 record.

If i request Top(10000) records the application work fine.

If i request all data this message show me:

Load operation failed for query 'getEmployees'. The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.OperationBase.Complete(Exception error)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadOperation.Complete(Exception error)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.<>c_*DisplayClass1b.b*_17(Object )

Answer (score 0):

You might need to [increase the maxItemsInObjectGraph](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/cs/blogs/dan/archive/2010/04/13/wcf-ria-services-not-found-error-message.aspx) property in the service config:

```
<services>
  <service name="SomeNs.MyService"
           behaviorConfiguration="BigQuota">
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="BigQuota">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="655360"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```